# Python: Pandas: Sort columns by cluster algorithm

Tags: python, pandas, heatmap, seaborn

I want to plot a clustered heatmap of a DataFrame. Using the `seaborn.clustermap`, I get very close to the result. But I only want the heatmap without the hierarchical tree and colobar, but I don´t know how to deactivate them.

[image]

If it´s not possible to deactivate these objects, do you know an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I don't know whether is possible to hide the dendogram. In the meantime, hoping that helps, you can hide the colorbar with:

```
cm = sns.clustermap(df)
cm.cax.set_visible(False)
```

where `df` is your dataframe.